# Specify tag for test cases using soapui-pro-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, automated-tests, soapui

It's possible to specify a tag for a test case in SOAP UI like this:

[image: SOAP UI Specify a Tag]

I'm using the SOAP UI Maven plugin to execute a functional test suite in different environments and it would be useful to be able to exclude some of the test cases by specifying a tag in the invocation.

It looks like there is no configuration parameter for the Maven plugin to specify a tag (so that only a subset of the tests cross cutting different test suites can be executed):

https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x.html

However it is possible to specify a tag when running via the GUI or command line:

http://readyapi.smartbear.com/features/automation/testrunner/cli

You can see from the above link that it is possible to specify tests which are tagged by using the -T switch.

Is this just a limitation of the Maven plugin?

Is it possible to simulate specifying a tag by reading an environmental variable during the Groovy startup script execution and disabling test cases which don't have the specified tag?

The Maven invocation is as follows:

```
mvn test -Dmyenv="dev" com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-pro-maven-plugin:5.2.1:test
```

The pom.xml looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>testing</groupId>
<artifactId>testing</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<prerequisites>
    <maven>3.0.5</maven>
</prerequisites>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>SmartBearPluginRepository</id>
        <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>mvnPluginRepository</id>
        <url>http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven/mule/dependencies/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>codehausPluginRepository</id>
        <url>https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/org/codehaus/mojo/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
            <artifactId>soapui-pro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.6</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
                    <artifactId>reflections-maven</artifactId>
                    <version>0.9.9-RC1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <projectFile>${basedir}/my-project</projectFile>
                <outputFolder>${basedir}/surefire-reports</outputFolder>
                <printReport>true</printReport>
                <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                <exportAll>true</exportAll>
                <reportFormat>HTML</reportFormat>
                <testFailIgnore>true</testFailIgnore>
                <coverage>true</coverage>
                <environment>${myenv}</environment>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are after. Something like this: https://siking.wordpress.com/2014/01/29/defining-test-categories-in-soapui/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if I am wrong about any of this or if there is a better way as I am rather new to using SOAP UI. If you give a significantly better answer, I will accept yours. I really hope that Smartbear will support a way of specifying tags in the Maven plugin.

I have established that it is [not possible to specify a tag via the Maven plugin](https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x.html) and that the server version of SOAP UI costs a [large amount of money](https://smartbear.com/product/ready-api/testserver/pricing/), so it's not possible in my situation to use the command line method of specifying a tag.

I thought about simulating test tags/categories by moving all of the tests that I want to include/exclude for an environment to a number of test suites. Unfortunately it appears to be only possible to run either only one test suite (by specifying one the the "testSuite" parameter) or all of the test suites (by leaving "testSuite" blank).

I thought I might be able to pull out the tag for a test case or suite using a Groovy script and use that to determine whether it should be run or not, but as far as I can tell, it's not possible to get the tag information for a test case or testSuite ([object model](https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/the-soapui-object-model.html) [API documentation](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/index.html?overview-summary.html)).

I settled on marking the test suites to be excluded with a custom property (testingOnly) and disabling those for a particular environment (Dev) in the project level "Setup Script":

```
// When running tests for the Dev environment, skip test suites with the property testingOnly=true

def disableSuitesWithProperty(def propertyName) {
    project.testSuiteList.each { testSuite ->
        def isPropertyTrue = testSuite.getProperty(propertyName)?.getValue()?.toBoolean() ?: false;

        if(isPropertyTrue) {
            log.info "[Project Setup Script] Will Skip Test Suite: ${testSuite.name}";
            testSuite.setDisabled(true);
        }
        else {
            log.info "[Project Setup Script] Will Execute Test Suite: ${testSuite.name}";
            testSuite.setDisabled(false);
        }
    }
}

if ("Dev".equals(project.getActiveEnvironmentName())) {
    disableSuitesWithProperty("testingOnly");
}
```

The suites are reenabled in the project level "TearDown Script":

```
// Reenable all test suites after all tests have run

for (testSuite in project.testSuiteList) {
    log.info "[Project TearDown Script] Reenabling Test Suite: ${testSuite.name}";
    testSuite.setDisabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to specify an environment variable to the Surefire plugin? If so, this should work:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Dmyenv=dev</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```